# Java Game Playing Area Difficulty

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

In many first person 2d games, there will be a huge playing field, but a small display area on your computer:

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+++++aaaaaa+++++++++++++++++++++++++
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+++++aaaaaa+++++++++++++++++++++++++
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+++++aaaaaa+++++++++++++++++++++++++
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+++++aaaaaa+++++++++++++++++++++++++
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

where "+" is the entire playing field and "a" is the displayable region on your screen.

I want to make a game like this where pressing the arrow keys will make you move across the entire playing field.

Question: Would I need to create a huge JPanel to accomplish this? (Bigger than the screen)

Comment: There is a good answer to this question here : http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/16570/scrolling-tile-system Check that out.

Comment: You use image tiles.  Break up the huge area into tiles that are 25% bigger than the displayable region.  When you detect the player crossing into another tile, you display both tiles until the player has moved into the next tile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you start a regular game, do you expect to find scrollbars for the whole level at the bottom and the side of your screen ? Or do you expect you can navigate (using your mouse/arrows/...) through the whole level.

In case of the first, be my guest and create a gigantic `JPanel` and put it in a `JScrollPane` but I strongly suggest to go for option 2.

For option 2 I outlined a possible approach in [another related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8672598/what-is-the-best-way-to-load-and-cache-images-in-java/8672945#8672945). That might be worth a look