# Buffered Image for Image Tiles

Tags: java, image, swing

I want to create a game where I want to have many image tiles which will respond to the arrow keys. Should I use BufferedImage to create every individual tile?

Refer to: [Java Game Playing Area Difficulty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10505000/java-game-playing-area-difficulty)

Comment: See also [`ScrollAction`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7203419/230513).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`RobotChase`](http://robotchase.sourceforge.net/) is a tile-based game that uses `BufferedImage` in this way. Alternatives include these:

- Implement the `Icon` interface, as shown in the examples cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10505042/230513).
- Set a component's text to a suitable Unicode glyph, as shown [here](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/buttons).

Comment: Exactly this is what I needed Point 2, though will take time for me to understand that example, too new to that stuff so a bit complicated :(