# JFrame blinking when change its contents and pack()

Tags: java, swing

I have a display that just shows a  score on a page:

for example:
JIMBOB
Total Score: 22

When a point is scored an event is triggered that updates the score and redraws the new score on the page:

```
public void showScore(String username, int score)
{
    contentPane.remove(layout.getLayoutComponent(BorderLayout.CENTER));
    score.setText("<html>" + username + "<br/>Total Hits: " + totalHits + "</html>");
    contentPane.add(score, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Every time a point is scored this function is called, it removes the old score message adds an new one then packs and redraws.

The problem is that the window flickers when drawing the updated frame. And it seems for a split second to be displaying the info unformatted

contentPane is a Container
and frame is a JFrame

Comment: We can help with if you create a minimal example. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Ok thanks will get to it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I would recommend to take a look at [how to use JPanels](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html) and other GUI components in Swing. You could use a [JPanel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html) to be added to the `contentPane` of your `JFrame`. Add a desired [LayoutManager that is fitting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for your need and use [it to position a JLabel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html) according to your wishes.

When you call your `showScore()` method, use `setText(String text)` on a `JLabel` instead of the `int score` that you supply as parameter.

In order to set the text using a String, you need to transform your `int score`. You can do either of the following two things (but use the first option):

```
label.setText(String.valueOf(score));
label.setText("" + score);
```

If you want the score label to appear or disappear, add/ remove it from the `JPanel` that you added to the `JFrame`. After adding it, call `setText()` on the label to display the score. Then, since you reset the text of the label, you should call `repaint()` on the `JPanel`. If you choose to add/ remove the `JLabel` instead of just changing its text you should also call `revalidate()` on the `JPanel`.

So all in all the function should look something like this (this is incomplete), assuming `totalHits` is actually your score.

```
// declare instance fields before constructor
// both variables are reachable by showScore() 
private JPanel scorePanel; 
private JLabel scoreLabel;

// in constructor of your class
scorePanel = new JPanel(); // initialize the JPanel
scorePanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout()); // give it a layout

scoreLabel = new JLabel(); // initialize the label

frame.add(scorePanel); // add JPanel to your JFrame

// method obviously outside constructor
public void showScore(String username, int score)
{
    // clear the JPanel that contains the JLabel to remove it
    scorePanel.removeAll();
    scoreLabel.setText("<html>" + username + "<br/>Total Hits: " + String.valueOf(score) + "</html>");
    scorePanel.add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    scorePanel.revalidate();
    scorePanel.repaint();
}
```

You could also declare and initialize the `JPanel` and `JLabel` in the `showScore()` method, making it more local. But then you would also need to call `pack()` on the `JFrame` and clear the previous `JPanel` from it every time you call the function.

.

Comment: WOW, thanks a lot brilliant informative and concise answer. Using revalidate(); and repaint(); on my Container (instead of frame.pack()) solved the issue completely. Is there an advantage to using a JPane over a Container? What is the advantage of using String.valueOf(totalHits) instead of just + totalHits?

Answer (score 2):

Invoking `pack()` will completely re-render the `JFrame`, a [top-level, heavyweight container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html) owned by the host platform. Instead, update the `JComponent` used to display the revised score. A complete example is cited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10508794/230513). Excerpted form [`RCStatus`](http://sourceforge.net/p/robotchase/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/src/org/gcs/robot/RCStatus.java),

```
public class RCStatus extends JPanel implements Observer {

    /** Update the game's status display. */
    public void update(Observable model, Object arg) {
        // invoke setText() here
    }
}
```

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3072979/230513) for more on the [observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, i ended up just using revalidate() then repaint(), instead of pack() and it solved my problems